# How to select case when a string is not equal a value then make another field blank?

Tags: sql

I have some columns like" OrderfieldNumber, Purchaser, Item. I'd like to create a statement in which:
case when the purchaser is not 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHK' then the OrderFieldNumber is blank. My purpose is just want to show OrderFieldNumber with those buyers only, I want to ignore other buyers without using Filter function. I tried:

```
case
when purchaser <> 'ABC' then OrderFieldNum = ' '
when purchaser <> 'DEF' then OrderFieldNum = ' '
when purchaser <> 'GHK' then OrderFieldNum = ' '
ELSE purchaser end as FilteredOrderField
```

But it doesn't seem to work out.

Answer (score 6):

```
case when purchaser not in ('ABC','DEF','GHK') 
     then ' '
     else OrderFieldNum 
end as FilteredOrderField
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a single statement, using `not in`:

```
(case when purchaser not in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHK') then ' '
      else purchaser
 end) as FilteredOrderField
```

The way you have it written, every non-NULL value will match one of the first two conditions, resulting in a blank.

Also, don't use an `=` in the `then` part of the `case`.